# On some phones custom notification doesn't have an arrow for collapse/expand

Tags: android, android-notifications

I try to create custom notification for my test project. I have remoteViews for collapse/expand view. My simple code is

```
public static void send(Context context, RemoteViews collapsedView, RemoteViews expandedView) {
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContent(collapsedView)
        .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
        .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();

    getNotificationManager(context).notify(0, notification);
}
```

This code works perfect, but i accidentally noticed that **on some phones(android 6.0)** when i get a custom notification it doest have an arrow for action collapse/expand.

Can you help me?

*Additionally* When i send custom notification i see:
1) the first state is expanded, not collasped (it is strange)
2) no action arrow for collapse

Comment: android 4.1+ for expanded, isnt it? I test on android 6.0

Comment: You haven't arrow on 6.0 but can you expand the notification ? With swipe to bottom

Comment: just edit question)

Comment: i try to collapse with swipe but it does not work

Comment: O_o i can to collapse notification using swipe with two fingers . Pinch swipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code for my notification and I don't think that I have this problem with Andorid 6.0 :

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setContentTitle("Some title")
                    .setContentText("Some text")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setSound(uriSound)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 20, 100})
                    .setShowWhen(true)
                    .setContentIntent(mainIntent)
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText("Some other text"))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build();
```

Comment: yep, its real good alternative solution. I just wanted to see the work of RemoteViews